# How to stop video download until a v-if condition is satisfied

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have multiple video files on my actual vue project. Each video has some rule which is controlled by v-if.

If v-if is true, then only I need to download the video file.

Currently what is happening is, even though we have v-if set to false, the video file is downloaded from network. Is there a way to stop this behavior ?

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <video v-if="showVideo" autoplay loop muted width="450" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"></video>
  <video v-if="showVideo" autoplay loop muted width="450" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"></video>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sajuthankathurai/62n5erju/26/

[image]

Comment: It is because you are using DOM template. Before Vue is even initialized on the page, browser parses whole HTML. And as it sees valid `video` element with valid `src` attribute, it will initiate download (way before any Vue code is executed). So I guess both solutions below should work. Another approach would be to wrap `video` element into custom component or use `<component is="video"`

Answer (score 1):

If you embbed your `video` in a `template`, that has the `v-if` property, the `video` tag does not seem to be evaluated on initialization:

```
<div id="app">
    <template v-if="showVideo">
        <video autoplay loop muted width="450" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"></video>
        <video autoplay loop muted width="450" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"></video>
    </template>
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked. Thanks @ingham. 
`<div id="app">
    <template v-if="showVideo">
        <video autoplay loop muted width="450" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"></video>
        <video autoplay loop muted width="450" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"></video>
    </template>
</div>`

Comment: You’re welcome, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but this works. You can put the `src` path in a computed property then only bind it on the video element when `showVideo` is `true`

```
<div id="app">
  <video v-if="showVideo" autoplay loop muted width="450" :src="downloadSrc"></video>
  <video v-if="showVideo" autoplay loop muted width="450" :src="downloadSrc"></video>
</div>

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
   showVideo : true
    
  },
  computed: {
    downloadSrc(){
        return this.showVideo ? 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4' : '';
    }
  }
})
```